# How can i grab some photos with python from website

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

I need to collect profile photos of the users  from the website.
I know python and django but don't know how can i do that.

Can someone guide me how can i make the python program so that i can list the website it only says o n their webiste only , not any external link and check for every page within that domain.

Edit:  Suppose that i want to collect all the thumnail photos of the users here in stackoverflow. Provided we don't have any all users page and go through. i want to go through all questions page then form there grab the photos and save to hardidsk with the userid so that we don't overrride

Comment: If you know the image URLs, then open them as a file, and `write` the `read` into a local file. Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("some_png.png","wb") as f:
     f.write(urllib2.urlopen("http://icons-search.com/img/yellowicon/TMNT_lin.zip/lin-png-256x256-Leonardo_256x256.png-256x256.png").read())
```

to find the image urls you will need to use [scrappy](http://scrapy.org/) (or a similar framework)

There are several tutorial on using it as a spider (e.g. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

Comment: i think i didn't explain that fully. Suppose that i want to collect all the thumnail photos of the users here in stackoverflow. Provided we don't have any all users page and go through. i want to go through all questions page then form there grab the photos and save to hardidsk with the userid so that we don't overrride

Comment: then you'll need to use scrappy or something to scrape the pages for data .... there are several tutorials on using scrappy ...

Comment: I tried the scrapy page but i ma not bale to download the latest pdf documentation. when i download it it comes out as 0.15.1. can you have a look at it

Comment: just use a tutorials to start ... your right looks like the pdf download is broken ... but the web docs are fine ...